# Module definition and usage in separate module

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am quite new at SAPUI5 and JS. There is something I do not understand well concerning the module definition and usage. Here is my context:

I want to create a Component `my.test.comp` that uses an external module object `my.test.comp.Service`.
So following the best practices, I have the following code:

**Service.js:**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function(BaseObject) {
  "use strict";

  var modulePath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("my.test.comp");
  var SERVICE_ROOT_PATH = modulePath.lastIndexOf("/") > 0
     ? modulePath.substring(0, modulePath.lastIndexOf("/"))
     : "/test";
  var Service = BaseObject.extend("my.test.comp.Service", {
    getServiceRootPath: function () {
      return SERVICE_ROOT_PATH;
    }
  });

  return Service;
});
```

And I use this in the **Component.js:**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Component",
  "./Service"
], function(Component, Service) {
  "use strict";

  return Component.extend("my.test.comp.Component", {
    init: function() {
      var serviceRootPath = Service.getServiceRootPath();
      jQuery.sap.log.error("ServicePathInfo : " + serviceRootPath);
    }
  });
});
```

When I run this, I get an error saying that `getServiceRootPath` is undefined, and throws an error.

So I changed the **Service.js** as follow:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function(BaseObject) {
  "use strict";

  var modulePath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("my.test.comp");
  var SERVICE_ROOT_PATH = modulePath.lastIndexOf("/") > 0
    ? modulePath.substring(0, modulePath.lastIndexOf("/"))
    : "/test";
  var Service = BaseObject.extend("my.test.comp.Service");
  Service.getServiceRootPath = function () {
    return SERVICE_ROOT_PATH;
  };

  return Service;
});
```

And now it is working well. I do not understand what are the differences.

Could someone explain me why?

Comment: Let us know if one of the answers could resolve the issue! If something is unclear, feel free to leave a comment! :) Otherwise, take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In JS, there are no classes. There are either plain objects (`{}`) or functions with constructor that can be called with `new`.

Accordingly, calling `.extend("...")` in UI5 returns a function, again, with its constructor as any other functions, ready to be used with `new`. Your module members (methods, properties, etc.) will be added to the *prototype* and not to the parent function (`Service`) itself.

```js
BaseObject.extend("my.test.comp.Service", {
  // methods in prototype ...
});
```

The required `Service` module (i.e. function) consists of only a constructor function (`Service.constructor`) and a *prototype* object (`Service.prototype`). That is why `Service.getServiceRootPath` was undefined in your first case. You'll need to call the constructor function with `new` first:

```js
return Component.extend("my.test.comp.Component", {
  init: function() {
    const service1 = new Service(); /* returns an object with ..
    *  __proto__: {
    *    getServiceRootPath: f ()
    *  }
    */
    const serviceRootPath = service1.getServiceRootPath();
    // ...
  },
});
```

<sup>(You could also directly access the method with `Service.prototype.getServiceRootPath` without `new`)</sup>

This also explains why `Service.getServiceRootPath` worked in the second case. You can add pretty much anything you like to an existing function since functions are ultimately objects too

---

It looks like your intention was not to create multiple "services" but a simple object with methods in it. In that case, just return a simple object with methods in your module definition.

```js
sap.ui.define([
 // Without "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function() {
  "use strict";
  //...
  return {
    getServiceRootPath: function () {
      // ...
    },
  };
});
```

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/Component",
  "./Service",
], function(Component, Service) {
  "use strict";

  return Component.extend("my.test.comp.Component", {
    init: function() {
      const serviceRootPath = Service.getServiceRootPath();
      // ...
    },
  });
});
```

This will work too.

Answer (score 0):

In your component.js you should import

"my/test/comp/Service"

instead of

"./Service"

Comment: Hello, What I wanted to do is using the first Service definition (first code) and use it in the component. Even by changing the dependency path it throws an error  saying Service.getServiceRootPath is not a function.